# MS Word 2010 Table of Contents Page numbers

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have just finished a Geo Internal Assessment, however before I hand it in, I want to make it look good, and thus have added both page numbers on the footer, and a table of contents. However the two confict!

The Footer Page Number counts the Table of Contents page as a page, and thus as Page 1 (while the next page, the "Introduction" Page is Page 2), while the Table of Contents thinks its not a page, and thus counts the next page (the "Introduction" page) as Page 1. However can I change this so they both agree on the page numbers?

Hope that makes sense, thanks

P.S Just in case that dont make sense:

Table of Contents: Page with heading "Introduction" is Page 1

Footer with Page Number: Table of Contents Page 1, page with heading "Introduction" is Page 2

Comment: Hmm, it works for me.  Did you update your table of contents?  When you select it, you should be able to click 'Update Table'.

Comment: @bfhd dam it.... forgot about that. Worked fine, thanks

Comment: please post it as answer bfhd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clicking 'Update Table' when your Table of Contents is selected.